# Sounds effect in Windows

Tags: windows, winmm

I am making a simple game.I am hitting a ball with my gun.When bullet will collide with ball it should give sound effect.Whether i hae done this but during sound effect my game becomes hold for a while.I don't want to keep in hold with sound effect.Below is the code for sound effect.

```
PlaySound("Data/Die.wav", NULL, SND_SYNC);  // Play The Death Sound
```

Comment: This is not really an OpenGL question. You might want to consider a better title and tag. It is more related to the winmm multimedia library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SND_ASYNC` not `SND_SYNC`

Comment: What is exact format to write it.I have a ".wav".Will it support to open it?